# Replicating existing Tridion 2009 CMS on a different Machine with the same license

Tags: 2009, migration, licensing

Both the Tridion(2009 CMS 5.3) CM server & CD server needs to be replicated on the new machines before we shut down the old machines.
We followed the installation manual for setting up CM & CD servers on new machine using the old licences we had. After installing the CM server we are unable to login to the Content Manager Explorer using the MTSUser or the system admin accounts.

Do we need to use a different login? Or Do we need to acquire new license files for this?

Comment: Did you update your users in database?

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Also, I hope you are on the same Domain as that of your old machine domain and the MTS User and CM Admin users are part of the domain and not the local server users

Comment: BTW, Tridion 2009 and Tridion 5.3 are different releases :) it doesn't matter in the context of this question, but it kinda messes my brain up...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The license is typically bound to a hostname and number of CPU Cores, if your new machine(s) has a different name or different number of CPU Cores then indeed this won't work and you'll need a new license file.

So, either rename the machines, or ask for a new license file. If it is a license violation issue, I am pretty certain it will be logged as such in the Windows Event viewer.

Comment: If you need license files for two different server names for a short period, it's worth asking if support will issue a temporary extra license file with a short expiry date. They do this sometimes if it's clearly for something practical like an upgrade.